# Stub file open in chefspec

Tags: rspec, chef-infra, chefspec

Hi am doing test with chefspec and I find the following error.

in `/cookbook/wordpress/recipes/default.rb`

```
wp_secrets = Chef::Config[:file_cache_path] + '/wp-secrets.php'

if File.exist?(wp_secrets)
  salt_data = File.read(wp_secrets)
else
  require 'open-uri'
  salt_data = open('https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/').read
  open(wp_secrets, 'wb') do |file|
    file << salt_data
  end
end
```

When I run ChefSpec, I get:

```
1) wordpress::default on Centos 6.5 includes depends recipes
   Failure/Error: end.converge('wordpress::default')
   Errno::ENOENT:
     No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /var/chef/cache/wp-secrets.php

   # /tmp/d20140617-408-1rx47um/cookbooks/wordpress/recipes/default.rb:77:in `from_file'
   # ./spec/centos/default_spec.rb:10:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
   # ./spec/centos/default_spec.rb:20:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

When I add a stub in `default_spec.rb`

```
before do
  File.stub(:exist?)
    .with("#{Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]}/wp-secrets.php")
    .and_return(true)
end
```

I get this error:

```
1) wordpress::default on Centos 6.5 includes depends recipes
   Failure/Error: end.converge('wordpress::default')
     <File (class)> received :exist? with unexpected arguments
       expected: ("/var/chef/cache/wp-secrets.php")
            got: ("/tmp/d20140617-479-1gqb2lc/cookbooks/chefignore")
      Please stub a default value first if message might be received with other args as well. 
   # ./spec/centos/default_spec.rb:10:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
   # ./spec/centos/default_spec.rb:20:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to stub the original call:

In ChefSpec 3:

```rb
File.stub(:exist?).and_call_original
File.stub(:exist?).with('/path/to/file').and_return('...')
```

In ChefSpec 4:

```rb
allow(File).to receive(:exist?).and_call_original
allow(File).to receive(:exist?).with('/path/to/file').and_return('...')
```

Comment: This helped me remove my deprecation warnings for RSpec as well. Thanks!